# Could not find files for the given pattern(s)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, solc

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json

install_solc("0.8.0")

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()
    print(simple_storage_file)

# Compile Code here
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.8.0",
)
# print(compiled_sol)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)
```

Comment: I believe that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896506/info-could-not-find-files-for-the-given-patterns-vsc-and-python) may help.

Comment: do you have  SimpleStorage  solidity file in your directory as this line is trying to open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r")

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to compile a Solidity contract file using the solcx library. The error message Could not find files for the given pattern(s) suggests that the library is unable to locate the file specified in the open function.

There are a few possible reasons for this error:

- The file specified in the open function ("./SimpleStorage.sol") might not exist in the current directory. Make sure that the file is present in the correct location and that the file path specified in the open function is correct.
- The file might exist, but the program doesn't have the necessary permissions to access it. Make sure that the program has the necessary permissions to read the file.
- There might be an issue with the solcx library itself. If you are using a version of the library that is not compatible with your version of Solidity, you may encounter this error. In that case, try installing a different version of the solcx library that is compatible with your Solidity version.